# How to calculate what i need to pay each month in a annuity type of loan?

Tags: calculation, financial-literacy, home-loan, annuity, amortization

Good or bad, how do get to the same number as the bank web calculator do with the following data:

Money loaned: 2 500 000 
Interest: 3.5%
Effective interest: 3.6%
Fee (each payment): 50
Number of payments pr year: 12
Cost of establishment: 2000
Number of years: 25

How much i need to pay each payment:  12566 <- how did they figure this number?

This is not dollars, lol. Swedish kroner ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use an amortization table like can be found [Here](http://www.vertex42.com/ExcelArticles/amortization-calculation.html).  The Forumula is not that complex

> [image: Formula]
>
> where:
> A = payment Amount per period 
> P = initial Principal (loan amount)
> r = interest rate per period
> n = total number of payments or periods

You will need to add 50 to  the A to account for the payment fee amount though.

Comment: Chad, annual interest is nearly 90K. How did you get 3000 as payment?

Comment: I reformatted to make it easier to read and see that it is indeed monthly payments

Comment: I missed an edit or two. OP has 12/yr now. And you deleted reference to 3000. No prob. You got the magic equation.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - I read the original post as 50 payments per year(which I admit confused me) with a 3.6 percent per payment fee.  The fee is 50 and there are 12 payments a year.  I just added html breaks into the text of the question where the OP had CR's which formatted the question how the OP intended and cleared things up.